# Can I have a variably modified vector in c++?

Tags: c++, stdvector

Is there any way to do this:

```
std::vector<char[foo]> bar;
```

I need ONE contiguous array of `char[foo]` but I don't know the length until runtime. I need to be able to add blocks of `char[foo]` dynamically.

I need the inner array to be exactly the right size, so if `foo` was 3:

[ [1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] ... [x, y, z] ]

I could implement it myself but don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: `std::vector< std::vector< char > >` ?

Comment: @KirilKirov trying that now.. looks like it's gonna work. Post answer?

Comment: @TonyD If I knew the value of foo at compile time

Comment: @trideceth12: yes - should have read more carefully... vector<vector<char>> is pretty heavyweight though.  Do you have any insight into the potential range of values of foo?

Comment: @TonyD it's set at runtime and doesn't change. Valid range is 1 < foo < UCHAR_MAX (the inner array is actually unsigned char)

Comment: What do you mean by, "I need a *contiguous array* of `char[foo]`"? On reading that I assumed you need the last byte of the first `char[foo]` to be adjacent to the first byte of the second `char[foo]`. In which case the answer is probably to use a `vector<char>` and multiply the size of it by `foo`. But you seem to accept `vector<vector<char>>`, which does not have this contiguity property.

Comment: @KirilKirov Yes, you are right. I removed my previous comment.

Comment: @SteveJessop - I think the OP needs only the inner array to have continuous memory, meaning the `char[foo]` part only. That's my understanding.

Comment: No I need the whole thing to be contiguous.. sorry I didn't explain it well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>I'd suggest using</strike>

```
std::vector< std::vector< char > >
```

`std::vector`'s internal memory is continuous.

---

Well, after a while, it appeared, that the whole memory must be continuous, which changes everything..

For this case, you can use directly `std::vector< char >::insert( pos, begin, end )` to [`insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) whole "chunks".

*Something like:* <sub>(I didn't test it, but you'll get the idea)</sub>

```
std::vector< char > bar;
// ..
{
    std::vector< char > buff( foo );
    // fill buff
    bar.insert( bar.end(), buff.begin(), buff.end() );
}
```

Only keep in mind, that this may/will cause reallocation of the internal memory and several copies of the elements, but we're talking about `char`, so it's not a big deal.

You can avoid these reallocations using `std::vector::reserve`, if you have idea about the final size of `bar`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint I think i'm going to go with `std::vector< std::valaray<char> >` though. As I need the inner arrays to be exactly the right size.

Comment: Scrap that.. I need the whole thing to be contiguous

Answer (score 3):

I'd create a container class myself, use `std::vector<char>` internally, and create a wrapper `slice` class which holds a pointer to the container class and an index into the vector. The container class would hold the length `foo`. The container would have an iterator returning slices, each `slice` would have an iterator returning `char`.

[edit]
This solution also allocates contiguous memory.

Answer (score 0):

After the question was reworded, you're probably looking for `std::vector< std::array<char, 3> >`

Memory will be contiguous for all elements. Assuming the last dimentsion is indeed a build time const.

Example:

```
std::vector< std::array<char, 3> > bar;
std::array<char, 3> foo = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
bar.insert(bar.end(), 10, foo);
```

Comment: Ahh I see a problem.. I need the inner array to be exactly the right size (not enough space and then some)

Comment: @trideceth12: That can be achieved with `.reserve`. Since you neither grow nor shrink your vectors, the downsides are not relevant to you.

Comment: @egur: No, a `vector<std::vector<char>*>` will be slower. It has poor locality of reference.

Comment: Note that a vector *can* shrink. Also, I think you are overplaying the cost of "deep" copying. This is really dependent on the vector's size, so your suggested solution could actually be slower due to the extra indirection and lower data locality.

Comment: @juanchopanza: the spec doesn' mandate vectors to shrink and in reality they don't (unless completely emptied).

Comment: @MSalters - indeed locality is hurt due to the extra indirection, but it pays back big time when the outer vector needs to grow a lot.

Comment: @egur: Why? You'd have to copy a pointer (either 4 or 8 bytes) instead of a `char[foo]`, which apparently can be 3 bytes. Even if `foo` was quite a bit bigger, you'd still expect access to be far more common than growth. For starters, you usually have at least 2 accesses: one write, one read.

Comment: @egur "the spec doesn't mandate vectors to shrink" is not the same as "they never shrink".  `vec.swap(smallerVec);` could easily shrink `vec`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: you're saying the same thing. If you delete elements from a vector it's capacity stays he same. Using swap is a not the trivial way of reducing a vector's memory footprint. i.e. the vector doesn't shrink automatically like `set` or `map`.

Answer (score -3):

`std::vector<char> bar(foo)`

Constructs foo chars with in the vector, but because char is a built in type the constructor won't be called so it will be garbage values until initialised.

Instead use `std::vector<char> bar(foo, char())` to fill it with initialised chars.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Actually you are wrong (besides the fact that it does not answer the question, at all). `std::vector` *will* initialize the memory with `T()` which is *value-initialization* and amounts to zero-ing the memory in the case of built-ins.